# ASP .NET JavaScript debugging on a Dell Laptop using the F12 key

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have done very little debugging on a laptop. In the past when I debug JavaScript I use the F12 key from a normal keyboard. The problem I am having right now is that I am trying to debug JavaScript on a Dell laptop. The problem is that when I press the F12 key the brightness indicator is displayed and the browser does not open up the JavaScript debugger. I have tried many combinations of keys with F12 but nothing will put the browser in JavaScript debug mode. Can anyone tell me how to open the browser's JavaScript debugger on a Dell Laptop using the F12 key?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Fn + F12 should work

Comment: It is not related to javascript and debugging. A lot of laptops "revert" by default the funtinal keys, so to get F1-F12 you need to use `Fn` button. Or change setting (sometimes in BIOS) Sometimes there is a [hotkey](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/how-to-revert-fn-keys-on-inspiron-15-5558/td-p/4734139) for that.

Comment: I tried to press the Fn and F12 key at the same time but still it did not work.